# Can I award a bounty to the OP?

Tags: support

If OP answered his own question, can I award a bounty to him?

I answered [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677585/upgrading-iwlwifi-7260-firmware-on-lenovo-t540p).

The OP's question was really good and with some of my help he found a great solution for this wireless adapter, that had problems for many years. Only disabling 802.11n workaround helped. There are lots of questions regarding this issue.

So if the OP writes an answer with the guide how to download and install firmware, can I offer and award a bounty to that answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. You can offer a bounty to any answer on any question (providing it's not your own, of course), including answers by the OP.

Comment: Thanks. That's good.

Comment: @Pilot6 the only extra feature OPs get from bounties is that bounties they offered get automatically rewarded to accepted answers after the timeout expires.

Comment: @muru I think this is applicable to all bounties. Not only offered by OP. And it is not the accepted answers but the highest voted answer >=2

Comment: @Pilot6 that gets bounty/2. An accepted answer for a bounty offered by OP gets the full bounty.

Comment: @muru OK, I see. Then I will get full bounty for [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/676000/wifi-problem-after-upgrade-14-10-to-15-04). So I can test it.

Comment: @Pilot6 just check the last paragraph of the help: http://askubuntu.com/help/bounty. The question you asked is also covered in the FAQ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work